# how do I convert csv file output from vertical to horizontal?

Tags: javascript, csv

I have a function that retrieves csv file content

```
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function () {
    console.log("This is the file Output Format \n" + reader.result);
    reader.readAsBinaryString(fileInput.files[0]);
};
```

My csv file function output file data in this format:

> 456789
>
> 454356
>
> 098569
>
> 856995

I want it to be in this format:

> 456789, 454356, 098569, 856995

how do I generate an horizontal file output like below?
[image]

Comment: Could you please add your `output` function to the question?

Comment: @KoshVery I use console.log

Comment: Just replace " " with ", "?

Comment: @RobG, it will replace linebreaks too, won't it?

Comment: @Ola, could you please clarify what you mean by 'vertical'?

Comment: @KoshVery—without knowing how the CSV will be parsed, it's impossible to know exactly what the outcome will be. If using a regular expression, `/ /` will only match spaces, not newlines which are `/\n/` or `/\r/` depending on the system.

Comment: @KoshVery I have updated the question with the different format of output. I had to manually typed the output format i wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your desired output does not contain `ID`, I've left the numbers only:

```
console.log(
   "This is the wanted Output Format \n" + 
   reader.result.split(/\s+/).splice(1).join(', ')
);
```